# Kill particular instance of Winword

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, ms-word

my application creates a new instance of winword embedded in a windows form.

```
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass()
```

Once the user finishes editing I close the window but the winword instance is still running in the background.

How can I kill that particular instance? I know how to kill all instances running on a machine but this isn't an option.

Comment: What if the instance you ended up using also has a user's document open in another window?

Comment: Its an in-house application with just a few users so they'll know not to create new documents from within the instance I've created for them. But if they have word open separately outside of my windows form I can't close it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with hanging interop COM objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503309/problem-with-hanging-interop-com-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
application.Quit()
```

In your code.

One thing I had to do on my system (it's an excel processing tool) is do a process kill if after the Quit things were still going on.

```
var openedExcel = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
            if (openedExcel.Any())
            {
                foreach (var excel in openedExcel)
                {
                    try { excel.Kill(); }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
```

Comment: where application is the instance of your Word ApplicationClass

Comment: But if application.Quit() didn't do the full job for you you resorted to killing all instances of excel? I can't do that

Comment: You probably would have to get the Instance Id of your exact one and Kill it.

Comment: Yeah, in my case I had done that since the processing was one-at-a-time and the server was dedicated to do that.

Comment: try this:
Dim processId As IntPtr

' we ignore the return value, since we don't care
' about the thread id...
GetWindowThreadProcessId (application.hWnd, processId)

Dim excelProcess As Process = Process.GetProcessById (processId.ToInt32())

Comment: found in google... Might help http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/369251-excel-process-id

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods for this (`Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is the most used I believe).

I suggest you should read the official documentation about releasing Office applications instances. it's available here: [Microsoft .NET Development for Microsoft Office / Releasing COM Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa679807%28office.11%29.aspx#officeinteroperabilitych2_part2_rco)

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you combine / add to Flaviotsf's answer the following code - which will determine what actual process is on the run:

```
Process[] myProcList = Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i <= myProcList.Length - 1; i ++) {
    string strProcessName = myProcList [i].ProcessName;

    string strProcessTitle = myProcList [i].MainWindowTitle();
         //check for your process name. 
    if (strProcessName.ToLower().Trim().Contains("access")) {

       myProcList [i].Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill particular instance of Winword Document.

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD"))
{
   if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Temp")) // Temp is document name.
    process.Kill();
}
```